# How to restrict Google Maps API key to website domain when you are testing on localhost?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-maps, google-api, google-api-key-restrictions

```
http://localhost:2200
```

I am testing my APP using the above URL, how can I restrict my google maps API key to only allow access via the above?

Comment: I think u can't. Just remove restirctions about domains.